# How to add jar file to xtext plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar

I need to add org.json jar to my xtext project.
I found many postings how to add jar to plugin but I dont understand how it works. Can someone provide a listing which steps (detailed) I have to do to achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to add a jar if you simply can install the plugin from eclipse orbit.

If you dont have a target platform

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Add ->  `https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20190602212107/repository/`
3. select `JSON Implementation for Java` (type `org.json` in the filter)
4. Next, Finish
5. restart
6. add `org.json` to required bundles

If you do have a `.target` file

add

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
    <unit id="org.json" version="1.0.0.v201011060100"/>
    <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20190602212107/repository"/>
</location>
```

if you really want to add a jar

1. create lib folder, paste jar
2. edit `build.properties` tick lib folder in `Binary build`
3. this should add `lib/` to `bin.includes`
4. open Manifest, go to runtime tab
5. under classpath click add and select `lib/xxxx.jar`
6. if you want to export the package from the plugin add the package under `exported package`